# How to get the time difference between two DateTime objects?

Tags: c#, datetime

```
 emp = moduleEmployee.ReturnEmployeeDAO().FetchEmployeeByID(emp);

 DateTime shiftStartTime = emp.Shift.StartTime;
 DateTime shiftEndTime = emp.Shift.EndTime;

 DateTime attTime = att.Time;
```

According to the above code my shiftStartTime is 11.00 PM and shiftEndTime is 7.00 AM. and attTime or signIntime is 1.00 AM. then how to calculate the difference between shiftStartTime and attTime. where the difference should be 2 hour.

please help.....

Thanks Rusho

Comment: Add 24 hours to the sign-in time if the shift's end time is less than the shift's start time and the sign-in time is past midnight.

Answer (score 5):

If you subtract two `DateTime` objects, you get a `TimeSpan`.

A `TimeSpan` then has properties for `TotalMilliseconds`, `TotalSeconds`, etc.

You want the **TimeSpan.TotalHours**

```
 int shiftHours = (attTime - shiftStartTime).TotalHours;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just subtract one time from the other and you'll get a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
TimeSpan diff = att.Time.Subtract(emp.Shift.StartTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

are you asking for something like this: ?

```
var timeSpan = (attTime - shiftStartTime);
```

the result is a TimeSpan where you can check how many hours, minutes, days, seconds and so on...

Comment: @PAryan, you need to accept this answer (or another one). That's different from voting it up.